# AFNetworking and Network Errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, afnetworking

I am using the `AFNetworking` framework to make several JSON web request.

During development if I fail to provide a required parameters or the Service developers have broken something :-) i receive a `500 error`

The Error block of `AFJSONRequestOperation` is correctly catching it. However i cannot see the  page body because `AfNetworking` is cancelling the request as soon as the error code in the head is received.

Is there some work around.  I would like to spit out the response body to the log.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You'll need to add the http Code 500 to the acceptable status codes and filter it on the success callback. There you will have a responseObject.

Comment: This is not advisable--please don't do this. AFNetworking makes a distinction between `success` and `failure` callbacks; if you want to log the content of the response, you can get that with `responseData` or `responseString` of the response object in the failure callback.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `responseData` or `responseString` property from the operation that's passed into the failure block.

Comment: Can't find one of these properties in the AFHTTPRequestOperation class

Comment: Mattt's really should be the accepted answer here. A '500' response should never be considered success.  Also, to answer your question LeonS, the `responseData` property is declared in the `AFURLRequestOperation` which the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is based on.

Comment: Note that the AFURLRequestOperation header file is not imported with the AFHTTPClient. This means that you'll have to import the header file before accessing the operation object's properties.

Comment: `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is now a subclass of `AFURLConnectionOperation`, as `AFURLRequestOperation` seems to have been obsoleted (I haven't checked the history though).  `responseData` is still there.