# AFHTTPClient Expected status code in (200-299), got 409

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have strange issue with AFHTTPClient, I am sending POST request like

```
NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:HTTP_SERVER];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: u];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient postPath:REGISTER
          parameters:params
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
                 int statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];
                 if(statusCode == 201){
                     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"register" sender:self];
                 }
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             }];
```

And server works fine ( in some cases server needs to answer me with code 409, API is made in that way), but I get error in XCode like  `Expected status code in (200-299), got 409`
How to solve this problem ( my hands are tied, I cannot change API and error code) ?

Comment: [error userInfo] will give you more information on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334274/afnetworking-and-network-errors):

You've got two options:

- add status code 409 to the list of acceptable status codes, and receive it in the success block **(bad)**
- deal with status code 409 in the failure block **(good)**

For the latter, if your `[operation.response statusCode]` is 409, you would use the `responseData` from `AFURLConnectionOperation` (superclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, you would need to import its header for this to work).